# Facebook Insights - not updating - no new data since the 18th

Tags: insight, facebook-insights

This is not a particularly technical question, but is anyone else having problems with their insights data? 
http://www.facebook.com/insights/?sk=ao_119242438097337
I've had no new data in insights since the 18th (6 days ago). Can anyone suggest what I should do - or who I might talk to?

Comment: This site is for programming questions.  Use this link to log a bug with Facebook: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/

Comment: This is a great question to ask on the Facebook Developers Group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/. More helpful guidance for Stack Overflow questions here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common on Facebook Insights.  Sometimes it gets stuck and fails to update for a few days until a Facebook Engineer gives it a good kick and it catches up again.

Comment: It's been almost a month now. Insights suddenly stopped on the 29th of May with no change on the website or app settings. Is it common with that long interruptions?